# How to draw toDataURL on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: javascript, jupyter

Please advise me how to draw image content on the jupyter notebook, the image content is generated by the following ijavascript (Javascript kernel for the Jupyter Notebook) and the image is stored on a canvas. The image content in text can be shown on the console with the function toDataURL(). However, I don't know how to display the image in binary on the jupyter notebook, please help how to display the image content on the jupyter notebook.

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , Image = Canvas.Image
  , canvas = new Canvas(200, 200)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '30px Impact';
ctx.rotate(.1);
ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

var te = ctx.measureText('Awesome!');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
ctx.lineTo(50 + te.width, 102);
ctx.stroke();

console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround solution, please feel free to comment.

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , Image = Canvas.Image
  , canvas = new Canvas(200, 200)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ,  fs = require("fs");

ctx.font = '30px Impact';
ctx.rotate(.1);
ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

var te = ctx.measureText('Awesome!');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
ctx.lineTo(50 + te.width, 102);
ctx.stroke();

// Save as png file
var pngfile = fs.createWriteStream("./testImage.png"),
    stream = canvas.pngStream();
stream.on("data", function(chunk){
    pngfile.write(chunk);
});
stream.on("end", function(){
    console.log("saved png");
});

$$.html("<img src=\"testImage.png\" />")
//console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
```